# Android shared elements don't work well on transparent view

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

[This screenshot has been slowed down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ13H.gif)

As you can see when `transitionAnimation` start . `EditText` background color is change . so people will see the `EditText` blinking .Why it blinking?because my `EditText` background color is #66eeeeee .if i use #eeeeee .it working well . how can i solve it?

Comment: Don't you think you answered in the third line of question? anyway what you want and where is code?

Comment: You mean you want to use alpha value with color? And it has problem?

Comment: @StanleyKou yes.it has a problem with shared elements